# Kafka mongoDB connector sink don't consume any events

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have a mongoDB Kafka connector that doesn't consume any event anymore.

My configuration is the following:

```
{
  "name": "event-mongodb-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector",
    "database":"Event",
    "collection":"Event",
    "topics":"Event",
    "connection.uri":"mongodb://uri",
    "mongo.errors.tolerance": "all",
    "mongo.errors.log.enable": "true",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "writemodel.strategy":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.writemodel.strategy.ReplaceOneBusinessKeyStrategy",
    "document.id.strategy": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.processor.id.strategy.PartialValueStrategy",
    "document.id.strategy.overwrite.existing": "true",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.type": "allowlist",
    "document.id.strategy.partial.value.projection.list": "date,clientId,orderId",
    "tasks.max": 2,
    "max.batch.size": 1000,
    "bulk.write.ordered": false,
    "errors.log.include.messages": true
  }
}
```

I actually have other connector like this one but for different even that are working fine.

The issue I'm facing is specifically for this topic, and I noticed that it accumulated a huge load of event in a particular partition.

[image: kafdrop screen]

In the logs I have this error:

> [2023-04-12 16:57:28,752] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=event-mongodb-sink-2-0} Commit of offsets threw an unexpected exception for sequence number 5: {Event-7=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1215069, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-6=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1217175, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-5=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1213520, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-4=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1217328, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-3=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1216765, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-2=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1216501, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-1=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=101580287, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}, Event-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=1214247, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask)
> org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Offset commit cannot be completed since the consumer is not part of an active group for auto partition assignment; it is likely that the consumer was kicked out of the group.
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:1163)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.doCommitOffsetsAsync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:981)
> at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsAsync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:948)

And also this info:

> [Consumer clientId=event-mongodb-sink-2-0, groupId=event-mongodb-sink-2] Giving away all assigned partitions as lost since generation has been reset,indicating that consumer is no longer part of the group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
> [2023-04-12 16:57:28,753] INFO [Consumer clientId=event-mongodb-sink-2-0, groupId=event-mongodb-sink-2] Lost previously assigned partitions Event-7, Event-6, TradeEvent-5, Event-4, Event-3, Event-2, Event-1, Event-0 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
> [2023-04-12 16:57:28,753] INFO [Consumer clientId=event-mongodb-sink-2-0, groupId=event-mongodb-sink-2] (Re-)joining group (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)
> [2023-04-12 16:57:28,753] INFO [Consumer clientId=event-mongodb-sink-2-0, groupId=event-mongodb-sink-2] Request joining group due to: need to re-join with the given member-id (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator)

And looking it up on internet, people claim it is related to the max.poll.interval.ms parameter that is too small compared to the time the consumer needs to process a batch and therefor it doesn't send the heartbeat and is kicked out.

Yet I set the max.batch.size of the connector to 1 to be sure that no process time would bother the consumer and still have the same issue. MongoDB is doing fine since I ingest other events with no issue, so i'm pretty convinced it's only on the consumer side.

When I create other mongoDB sink connector (same purpose different name) for this same topic, the same behavior reproduce. On the other hand when I create a console consumer, some events are consumed but not from the overloaded partition (the number 1).

Can someone explain this beahvior ?

Comment: Unrelated to the error, but you should use 8 tasks for the connector since you have that many partitions

Comment: Have you tried looking at the /status endpoint of the connector? Is it crashing?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I used 8 partitions in my last attemp. It actually managed to consume some events again but VERY VERY SLOWLY. And at some point, it got kicked out as well. The status of the tasks seems to be "RUNNING" all the time even when the exception pops.

Comment: Well, you have hundreds of millions of events, but are only batching 1000 at a time, which is a blocking operation... You could make it 5000, for example, but I wouldn't suggest making it too large to risk OOM exception

Comment: Initially I had nothing precised for this parameter which that it was taking the "entire" batch of event, I don't really know how much it was taking though.

Comment: Yes, I think you'll want to set it to a number, plus potentially set `consumer.override.max.poll.records` to something higher than its default of 500

Comment: But this parameter isn't precised anywhere in the documentation. I don't think I have access to it from the mongoDB connector, don't I ?

Comment: It's not a Mongo property. That one is documented in Kafka documentation and available for all sink connectors... Basically, Kafka is polling its own batch. Then you're telling the Mongo client how many records from Kafka's consumer batch you want to write in one `bulkWrite` call. Ideally that's some factor of the consumer `max.poll.records`, but it cannot be any larger

Comment: I understood it wasn't a mongoDB property, I assumed that the maintainer of the kafka mongoDB connector jar didn't expose those properties since they are not mentioned in the doc.

Comment: It shouldn't need to be, since it's just a generic Kafka Connect property. Connector class, Topics and tasks.max isn't in the Mongo docs either https://kafka.apache.org/documentation#connect

Comment: yes tasks.max is in the mongoDB connector documentation. But indeed you're right I could set the paremeters you mentioned. Yet, consumer are still kicked out. I will try to play with the paremeters more.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Whatever value I put, it always end up to time out for this topic. Regardless I don't see why it would time out when the value I put to max.batch.size and max.poll.records are small. How is it possible that the connector don't give heartbeat when he only have to manage hundreds of events ? It should be the opposite. I even put max.poll.interval.ms of 1 hour right now and at somepoint when it reaches 2 hours, it ends up timing out.

Comment: `kicked out of the group` error is not a timeout. It means your MongoClient is doing too much work (or blocking), probably because you are trying to consume and write too much, and so Kafka consumer group will rebalance, "kicking out" other previous consumers.